# image stuck - 'pending' network status for an src/ng-src

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, src

I'm writing an application whose data has multiple image links, that I assign into ng-src (Angular's src directive). every once in a while, the image is stuck and I see a 'pending' status on the network debugging tab. The image got received after a minute or so. during that same minute, I take the image URL and put it in a different browser, and the image is shown immediately

any ideas what it could be?

thanks much
Lior

Comment: Don't have an answer but have you tried running this locally and against a server? Is the behavior the same?  I'm wondering if there's a chance it's actually a server side error and perhaps you need to investigate the server logs.

Comment: thanks @shaunhusain images are hosted on a server - that's a given architecture... and yes, i'm going to investigate logs. but wondered if any leads

Comment: Are there any other network connections to the server when the 'pending' message appears? It sounds like the network stack is waiting for a free connection. Checking the server logs would reveal when the request actually hits the server and how long the server takes to send a response so that would be of a great help.

Comment: yes, going that route. it also happens on IE and FF so it suggests it is a server issue. thanks

Comment: I am also having this exact same issue. The whole site is in development right now running locally. Images are in an "image" subfolder. More often than not, all images don't load and show up as "pending" in the Network console. **Request URL:http://localhost:9000/images/defaultProfileImg.png** Request headers: **Accept:image/webp,*/*;q=0.8**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this while running angular/yeoman/grunt.

I seem to have fixed it by using `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` in my URL.

Then the images all showed up.

Although now I see the old URL is working…?

Probably worth trying, at any rate.

Comment: Same thing for me, switching to `localhost` worked and also magically made `127.0.0.1` work. FWIW, I was also working on an angular app using Gulp and LiveReload. Putting this in the "it works and I have no idea why" folder